# How do I know if I have committed kufr (doubts)

Tags: allah, kufr

I am getting these doubts about Allah but I'm not sure if I have commited kufr or not.

How do I know that I have commited kufr ? I'm a bit scared I have.

Answer (score 1):

When Shaytan can no longer convince you or lure you towards grave sins, he will attempt to make you overthink and cause you to be hyper skeptical in order to ruin you from the inside out (Waswasah). Don't turn away to these doubts and I advise you to seek Allah’s Protection from Satan. Moreover, you ***must*** read these Hadiths: [(1)](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5111), [(2)](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5112), [(3)](https://sunnah.com/muslim:132a), and [(4)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3276). May Allah The Almighty always keep you steadfast on the deed brother!